# Strange Chrome notification on Android 8.0

Tags: android

I just got a notification in French (I live in a French speaking country):
Sincere congratulations, you won a Galaxy S8 phone.

The notification has the icon of Chrome  and is coming from news3.lapetinsatlame.men

When I clicked on it took me to https://mobile-fb.com....

I installed Malwarebytes and after a full scan it did not find anything.

Earlier in the morning I was checking some cartoons for my kids, and it could be because of that, because afterwards on my PC watching the same cartoons, Kaspersky complained and blocked a request from a malicious website:

Here is the log:

```
26.08.2018 17.44.56;Download blocked;https://pushtrust.com/notifications/push/cpm/3/videoplayer/index.html?subid_short=1fa18b71b7ca5918ca38f22ab52906ed&p1=https%3A%2F%2Fzme8o3l1c4.com%2Frmavev10%3Fkey%3Dd47d042b3c4d449dd309e5f3f7758d8e;not-a-virus:HEUR:AdWare.Script.Generic;https://pushtrust.com/notifications/push/cpm/3/videoplayer/index.html?subid_short=1fa18b71b7ca5918ca38f22ab52906ed&p1=https%3A%2F%2Fzme8o3l1c4.com%2Frmavev10%3Fkey%3Dd47d042b3c4d449dd309e5f3f7758d8e;Google Chrome;Adware;08/26/2018 17:44:56
26.08.2018 19.14.21;Task started;Web Anti-Virus;08/26/2018 19:14:21
26.08.2018 19.07.08;Task started;Web Anti-Virus;08/26/2018 19:07:08
26.08.2018 18.42.43;Task started;Web Anti-Virus;08/26/2018 18:42:43
26.08.2018 17.44.56;Object (file) detected;https://pushtrust.com/notifications/push/cpm/3/videoplayer/index.html?subid_short=1fa18b71b7ca5918ca38f22ab52906ed&p1=https%3A%2F%2Fzme8o3l1c4.com%2Frmavev10%3Fkey%3Dd47d042b3c4d449dd309e5f3f7758d8e;not-a-virus:HEUR:AdWare.Script.Generic;https://pushtrust.com/notifications/push/cpm/3/videoplayer/index.html?subid_short=1fa18b71b7ca5918ca38f22ab52906ed&p1=https%3A%2F%2Fzme8o3l1c4.com%2Frmavev10%3Fkey%3Dd47d042b3c4d449dd309e5f3f7758d8e;Google Chrome;Adware;08/26/2018 17:44:56
```

It could be something else though, the above logs are my only possible explanation...
Do I need to worry about my phone?

I'm making payments from the banking app, checking work email... I'd like to keep this phone as clean/secure as possible.

It's a Galaxy S7 and a few days ago I installed a new security patch (pushed by Samsung/Google), thus it has the 1 July Security Patch level.

If I got "infected", even a light "infection", how can I clean my phone?

Many thanks for your answers.

P.S. Obviously I regret visiting the cartoons website and will not allow my kids to watch cartoons on that website

Comment: Dishonest ads that leads you to websites that propose fake offers and fake "gifts" are sadly common even on mainstream news websites

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that the website is using the [HTML5 notification mechanism](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/notification) to send a notification (in this case ads) to the browser.  And you probably accepted that the site can send you notifications. See [this support document](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/3220216?co=GENIE.Platform%3DAndroid&hl=en) on how to manage which site can send you notifications.